# unittesting(Python), test if function returns an array

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a python function somefunc(), that must return an array like this `[1, 2, 3]`. Now I'm writing a unittest to check what this functions return:

```
class TestingFunctionsTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_somefunc(self):
        #what to write here ?
```

I'm new in python testing, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
from mymodule import somefunc

class TestingFunctionsTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_somefunc(self):
        self.assertEqual(somefunc(), [1, 2, 3])
```

This calls the function and asserts that the return value must be equal to `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Thanks very much, can you plz tell how to check if the function returns integer for example ? Or, if you can, give some link with instructions how to use assertEqual() ?